# NHibernate With SQL Server Full Text

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, full-text-search

How-tu use NHibernate (with Fluent NHibernate) with SQL Server Full Text Search ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2386233). This is available (at least using HQL extending the dialect as shown) in NH 2.1. What version are you using?

Comment: Since external links may go broken, may you edit your answer to include the solution here without depending on the link to remain live? By the way, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21059722/1178314) seems to provide a better implementation.