# NHibernate LinqToHqlGenerator for SQL Server 2008 full text index 'Containing' keyword

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, full-text-search

I think I'm missing something fundamental when implementing a LinqToHql generator class.

I've successfully registered the SQL Server 2008 `contains` query using a custom dialect with this registration:

```
RegisterFunction("contains", new StandardSQLFunction("contains", null));
```

I have only one class with a full text index to be queried:

```
public class SearchName
{
  public virtual Guid Id {get; set;}
  public virtual string Name {get; set;} // this is the search field
}
```

The contains function works properly in HQL:

```
var names = Session.CreateQuery("from SearchName where contains(Name,:keywords)")
                    .SetString("keywords", "john")
                    .List();
```

and the generated SQL is perfect:

```
select searchname0_.Id   as Id4_,
       searchname0_.Name as Name4_
from   Search_Name searchname0_
where  contains(searchname0_.Name, 'john' /* @p0 */)
```

The next challenge was to implement the Linq to HQL generator:

```
 public class MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry :
    DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
    {
        public MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
        {
            this.Merge(new ContainsGenerator());
        }
    }

    public class ContainsGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
    {
        public ContainsGenerator()
        {
            SupportedMethods = new[] {
                ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<SearchName>(d => d.Name.Contains(String.Empty))
          };
        }

        public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method,
          System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject,
          ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
          HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            return treeBuilder.MethodCall("contains",
                    visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression(),
                    visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression()
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Calling the method like this:

```
var namesLinq = Session.Query<SearchName>().Where(x=> x.Name.Contains("john")).ToList();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to override the built-in `Contains` method, and the generated SQL is wrong:

```
select searchname0_.Id   as Id4_,
       searchname0_.Name as Name4_
from   Search_Name searchname0_
where  searchname0_.Name like ('%' + 'john' /* @p0 */ + '%')
```

Is it not possible to override the default `Contains` method, or have I just made a silly mistake?

PS - I'm using NHibernate 3.3.1.4000

Comment: There may be another approach to take, have you seen this blog post http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html - shows how to extend the LINQ provider (you may not be able to override `Contains` as a registered function)

Comment: @Rippo Yes, I've seen that post.  It provided most of the information I used to create my own extension.

Comment: What I am saying is you may need come up with another method name instead of `Contains` use  `FullTextContains` as Fabio is using `IsLike` which translates to `%foo%`

Comment: Yes, that was one of my three problems.  See the answer for details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I've finally figured it out!

First, I managed to delete the registration code from my configuration:

```
...
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
     {
        cfg.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
        ...
     }
```

Second, don't try to override the existing Linq behaviors.  I moved my Contains extension method to the full-text class.

Third, build the Hql tree correctly.

For others trying to implement a SQL 2008 Free-text contains search, here's the complete implementation:

```
public static class DialectExtensions
    {
        public static bool Contains(this SearchName sn, string searchString)
        {
            // this is just a placeholder for the method info.  
            // It does not otherwise matter.
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
    {
        public MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
            : base()
        {
            RegisterGenerator(ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() =>
                 DialectExtensions.Contains(null, null)),
                 new ContainsGenerator());
        }
    }

    public class ContainsGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
    {
        string fullTextFieldName = "Name";

        public ContainsGenerator()
            : base()
        {
            SupportedMethods = new[] {
                ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() =>
                DialectExtensions.Contains(null, null))
          };
        }

        public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method,
          System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject,
          ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
          HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            // cannot figure out how to interrogate the model class to get an 
            // arbitrary field name...
            // perhaps the RegisterGenerator() call above could be used to pass a
            // property name to the ContainsGenerator constructor?
            // in our case, we only have one full text searchable class, and its
            // full-text searchable field is "Name"
            HqlExpression[] args = new HqlExpression[2] {
                 treeBuilder.Ident(fullTextFieldName).AsExpression(),
                 visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression() 
                 };
            return treeBuilder.BooleanMethodCall("contains", args);
        }
    }
```

For the above to work, you must have declared and used your custom dialect:

```
public class CustomMsSql2008Dialect : NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
{
    public CustomMsSql2008Dialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction(
            "contains",
            new StandardSQLFunction("contains", null)
            );
    }
}
```

Then you can use your new contains search this way:

```
var namesLinq = Session.Query<SearchName>().Where(x => x.Contains("john")).ToList();
```

... and the resulting SQL is perfect! (at least if you only have one table you're performing full-text searches on)

**EDIT: UPDATED IMPLEMENTATION TO SUPPORT MORE THAN ONE FULLTEXT 'Contains' SEARCH PER QUERY.**

Here's the revised version:

```
public static class DialectExtensions
    {
        public static bool FullTextContains(this string source, string pattern)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
    {
        public MyLinqtoHqlGeneratorsRegistry()
            : base()
        {
            RegisterGenerator(ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => DialectExtensions.FullTextContains(null, null)),
                          new FullTextContainsGenerator());
        }
    }

    public class FullTextContainsGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
    {
        public FullTextContainsGenerator()
        {
            SupportedMethods = new[] { ReflectionHelper.GetMethod(() => DialectExtensions.FullTextContains(null, null)) };
        }

        public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method,
          System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject,
          ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
          HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            HqlExpression[] args = new HqlExpression[2] { 
                visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
                visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression() 
            };
            return treeBuilder.BooleanMethodCall("contains", args);
        }
    }
```

To use the revised version, the syntax is slightly different:

```
var namesLinq = Session.Query<SearchName>().Where(x => x.Name.FullTextContains("john")).ToList();
```

Comment: This is pretty good if you never what to use the default linq for contains `%foo%`... Good job

Comment: Well, searching through a few million records using LIKE to query a varchar(300) field was not making me happy!  Also, while NHibernate.Search is available (and is a superior choice to using Fulltext within the database instance), not everyone has the ability to add a new Lucene environment to their production systems on the fly.

Comment: Have to agree with Rippo. Nice, even great, to see how Configurable and Extensible NHibernate is. good! +1

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. I was not saying use %foo%.  But  register a `FreeTextContains` function same way Fabio is using islike. I like to stick to the principle of least surprise. Like what you done though.

Comment: @DavidMontgomery, for readability of your answer, may you remove or at least put at the end the obsolete code you had first written? (Side note : `MethodCall` may be more appropriate than `BooleanMethodCall` since [`freetext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) and [`contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) are predicate function who do not return anything: it would not work to try comparing their 'result' to anything.)